# Transporting vehicle with no registration

Tags: registration

If I buy a car in another state and want to drive it back, I have the problem that the car will have no registration.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: talk to the dmv in both states.  Obviously talk to your insurance co as well.

Comment: https://dor.georgia.gov/transfer-title-and-license-plate-another-state-or-country ... does this help?

Comment: Stick it on a trailer or get a transport company...

Answer (score 1):

If you're buying from a dealer they will give you temporary registration and you'll be fine.

For private party, depending on your state (and perhaps the states you're driving through), you'll need at the very least the signed title to your name.  Some states will issue a temporary permit for this exact purpose.  Call your local DMV and ask.

Comment: Ok, if I am in Massachusetts and I go to Florida to buy the car from a private party, then I am now in Florida and have title. How do I get a temporary registration in Massachusetts if I am in Florida?

Comment: @CooterDavenport You don't, you get a Florida [temporary tag](http://fdhsmv.rapidinsites.com/answer/temporary-tag).